Firestore Implementing Cloud Syncing for Paid Users & Offline Cache for Unpaid Users in Flutter?
I'm building an app in Flutter that uses Firestore as its backend database. I want to implement online syncing only for paid users, while unpaid users can use the local database cache only. I've set up a system where I disable network access for unsubscribed users and enable it when they subscribe.
However from my understanding, this is not how it is intended to be used. When an unpaid user subscribes, all their accumulated offline transactions will be synced individually to Firestore, which could result in a large number of transactions.
My Firestore database is structured as User ID > Lists > Items. How can I handle scenarios where only paid users have cloud syncing capabilities? I am sure I could use SQLite for unpaid users and try syncing somehow but I was hoping to just use Firestore to keep it simpler. What is the recommended way to handle a situation like this?
I've provided my current implementation below for reference:
  ListProvider(this.subscriptionProvider) {
    _listsRef = _firestore.collection('lists'); // Initialize here in the constructor body
    _initializeDataFlow();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeDataFlow() async {
    subscriptionProvider.addListener(_handleSubscriptionChange);
    await _handleSubscriptionChange();
  }

  Future<void> _handleSubscriptionChange() async {
    if (subscriptionProvider.hasActiveSubscription) {
      await _firestore.enableNetwork();
      print("Network enabled: Syncing with Firestore.");
    } else {
      await _firestore.disableNetwork();
      print("Network disabled: Using local cache only.");
    }
    _listenToLists();
  }

  void _listenToLists() {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _listsRef.orderBy('orderField').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      _lists = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ListModel.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscriptionProvider.removeListener(_handleSubscriptionChange);
    super.dispose();
  }



You could disable network access for the Firestore client for your unpaid users.
This used to be an anti-pattern in the early years after Firestore's release, as the SDKs performance would deteriorate linearly with the number of pending writes. But nowadays the SDKs also keep a snapshot of the latest version in the cache too, and can perform indexed queries while offline, so performance is actually quite good.

That is what i was hoping i could do so are you saying that if a user downloads the app and uses it for 5 months accumulating 50,000 transactions like editing the name of items, deleting and adding items offline it will not run all 50,000 transactions when they purchase a subscription and network access is enabled? I'm still learning how firestore works.

once you enable network it will have perform every pending write operation, as each of those ends up in a separate state (that for example, your server-side security rules may reject).

So that does mean 50,000 transactions would all take place that is what I was wondering. If for example a user taps a check box 1000 times offline its going to change the field in firestore from true to false 1000 times when going online instead of just understanding that that the field is false at its current state and setting it to that.

Yup, that's what I think will happen. It might be worth trying it for yourself though.
